# Is it possible to Declare but not Instatiate a Spied Object in Mockito using @Spy Notation?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, spy, partial-mocks

I am writing some JUnit tests for legacy code and I am a big fan of using annotations. I would like to know if it is possible to create a declaration to a spied object and later instantiate it. The reason I ask is because I have a class with a non-null constructor. The values for this constructor are not known until after setup of the test cases. The code below shows what I would like to do:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ObjectUndertestTest {

    @Spy private SomeClassToSpy someClassToSpy; 
    private Integer parameterOne;
    private Integer parameterTwo;

    @Before
    public void setupTest() {
        parameterOne = 1;
        parameterTwo = 2;
        someClassToSpy = new SomeClassToSpy(parameterOne, parameterTwo);
    }
}
```

The only way that I can see to be able to do this is to mix my syntax and use the traditional spy(object to mock) notation. That is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ObjectUndertestTest {

    private SomeClassToSpy someClassToSpy; 
    private Integer parameterOne;
    private Integer parameterTwo;

    @Before
    public void setupTest() {
        parameterOne = 1;
        parameterTwo = 2;
        someClassToSpy = new SomeClassToSpy(parameterOne, parameterTwo);
        SomeClassToSpy spySomeClassToSpy spy(someClassToSpy);
    }
}
```

Or something similar. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Beware that `@Spy` isn't really a documentation annotation: It is an instruction for MockitoJUnitRunner (et al) to *initialize the spy automatically for you according to its documented usage patterns*. Though annotations are useful and informative, I think it may cause *more* confusion to use the annotation for its name and not its semantics.

That said, if it's just a matter of constructing an instance with your chosen constructor arguments, you can call the constructor directly and explicitly and use Mockito's initialization to wrap it in a spy (as in the [@Spy docs](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Spy.html)):

```
@Spy private SomeClassToSpy someClassToSpy = new SomeClassToSpy(1, 2);
```

Though you'd be right to favor @Before methods over class initializers or constructors, this is an explicitly-documented method of initialization and one unlikely to cause test pollution or initialization-order problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd like to make a reference to the object type without instantiating it until later so that I can test multiple inputs. This gives access to the object in any other test case. After extensive playing around, I have found it is not possible to do it with annotations. It requires a real reference to the object, and then using the spy(someClass) reference. With an abstract class, this was even more difficult, but works just fine in Mockito 1.10